# Where multi column adds up over 16

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to pull all records that have the engineer and has an overall score of 16 or higher.

value_money, quality_service, friendliness, response_time are all fields in the same table.

I'm trying to add all these and perform a WHERE.

This is what I've got so far

```
SELECT *,
value_money+quality_service+friendliness+response_time AS overall
FROM feedback
WHERE engineer LIKE '%Chris Gauden%'
AND
overall < 16
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0, 15
```

And this is the error i'm getting.

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'overall' in 'where clause'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alias cannot be used in `WHERE`. Do either

```
SELECT *,
value_money+quality_service+friendliness+response_time AS overall
FROM feedback
WHERE engineer LIKE '%Chris Gauden%'
AND
value_money+quality_service+friendliness+response_time < 16
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0, 15
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT *,
value_money+quality_service+friendliness+response_time AS overall
FROM feedback
WHERE engineer LIKE '%Chris Gauden%'

)a WHERE overall < 16
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0,15
```

Comment: Thanks i used the first example.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use alias in there WHERE clause.
You have to use full `value_money+quality_service+friendliness+response_time` combination.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to move the condition to the `having` clause:

```
SELECT *, value_money+quality_service+friendliness+response_time AS overall
FROM feedback
WHERE engineer LIKE '%Chris Gauden%'
HAVING overall < 16
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0, 15;
```

This is a MySQL extension and will not work in other databases.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what database your using but try something like this:

```
SELECT *,
value_money+quality_service+friendliness+response_time AS overall
FROM feedback
WHERE engineer LIKE '%Chris Gauden%'
AND
SUM(value_money+quality_service+friendliness+response_time) < 16
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0, 15
```

Answer (score 0):

You since overall isn't a column in that table, you can't reference it in the `where` clause.

You could do something like this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT *,
           value_money+quality_service+friendliness+response_time AS overall
    FROM feedback
    WHERE engineer LIKE '%Chris Gauden%'
) AS ComputedTable
WHERE
    overall < 16
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0, 15
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your server doesn't support that. If that's the case, I can think of two options. Subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *, value_money+quality_service+friendliness+response_time AS overall
FROM feedback
WHERE engineer LIKE '%Chris Gauden%') AS t
WHERE overall < 16
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0, 15
```

Or repeating the equation:

```
SELECT *,
value_money+quality_service+friendliness+response_time AS overall
FROM feedback
WHERE engineer LIKE '%Chris Gauden%'
AND
value_money+quality_service+friendliness+response_time < 16
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0, 15
```